# nginx pass REMOTE_USER to apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, authentication, mod-rewrite

I am running an apache2 instance behind an nginx reverse-proxy, with nginx performing basic authentication and apache2 serving up Nagios cgi scripts.

I am able to send the authenticated user from nginx to apache (currently using X-Forwarded-User header set to $remote_user) - but I am struggling to get apache2 to recognize this header and set the REMOTE_USER env variable before it executed the CGI script.

I believe mod_rewrite might be able to do this, but all the examples I have seen relate to the reverse scenario, where apache2 is sending REMOTE_USER downstream to another backend server.

Is it even possible to set REMOTE_USER within apache to something outside the realm of apache's own mod_auth module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Apache's `mod_setenvif` and `SetEnvIf` directives.

e.g.:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-User (.*) REMOTE_USER=$1
```

Requires Apache 2.0.51 or later. [Docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html).